# Reuse SQL expression with changed variables

Tags: sql, perl

I have a Perl DBI statment

```
my $sql_statement = "select c.* ".
                    "from meter_category c ".
                    "where c.category = ".$current_category." ".
                    "and c.effective_date <= ".
                    $DBHdl->quote($time_stamp)." ".
                    "and c.meter_size = ".$meter_size." ".
                    "order by c.effective_date desc ; ";
```

`$DBHdl` is an Informix database handle.

The statement looks like this:

```
select c.* 
from meter_category c 
where c.category = 1 
and c.effective_date <= '09/20/2013'
and c.meter_size = 0.63 
order by c.effective_date desc ;
```

At some point in my function, I want to set `$current_category` to 2, and then modify $sql_statement.

After

```
$current_category = 2;
eval $sql_statement
```

does not change $sql_statement, so `c.category = 2`.

Is there a way to perform the substitution, or do I have to re-issue the statement?

I use the following code to prepare and execute the query for each value of $current_category.

```
my $ptSelHdl = $DBHdl->prepare($sql_statement);

die("Could not prepare \$sql_statement for meter charge.\n")
 if(!$ptSelHdl || !$ptSelHdl->execute);
```

Comment: When concatenating strings, you do not need to break your strings to put in variables, you can put them directly into the string, e.g. `"foobar = '$foobar'"`.

Comment: From your excerpt, you might benefit from DBI's [RaiseError](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#RaiseError) attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) (the `?`s in the statement below) to indicate values you will supply when executing the statement:

```
my $sql_statement = "select c.* ".
                    "from meter_category c ".
                    "where c.category = ? ".
                    "and c.effective_date <= ?".
                    "and c.meter_size = ? ".
                    "order by c.effective_date desc ; ";

my $sth = $DBHdl->prepare($sql_statement)
    or die "Could not prepare \$sql_statement for meter charge: " . $dbh->errstr;

$sth->execute($current_category, $time_stamp, $meter_size)
    or die "Could not execute \$sql_statement for meter charge: " . $dbh->errstr;
```

Then you can execute it multiple times with different parameters, e.g:

```
# Modify $current_category and re-execute
$current_category = 2;
$sth->execute($current_category, $time_stamp, $meter_size)
    or die "Could not execute \$sql_statement for meter charge: " . $dbh->errstr;
```

Using placeholders is a good practice to get in to as they will also defend you against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks should any of your variables come from untrusted sources.

Comment: This must be an Informix thing then, because I execute those same commands. I am re-editing the OP to show those commands I use. My workaround is I'm modifying $sql_statement, and then preparing and executing the newly modified statement.